# Load specific settings when user try to acces to an app (multi app django)

Tags: python, django, settings

I have a django project with several app. Each is linked to a different DB and may have different settings. I use mod_wsgi with apache.
Actually, I'm following one of the methodology found [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings) : read a .ini file.

**How can I load the settings.ini specific to my app when a user try to access it ?**

I can load/read a specific settings.ini in my settings.py and it works fine. I want to load/read only the settings.ini of the app requested by the user.

**How to know the app to give the right path to load ? (via URL ?)**

Please see my simplified project tree :

```
├── django.wsgi
├── manage.py
├── global
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── my_app1
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.ini
│   └── ...
├── my_app2
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.ini
│   └── ...
```

My specific settings file is read at the top of my setting.py :

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('/path/to/my/settings.ini')

DEBUG = config['debug']['DEBUG']
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = config['debug']['TEMPLATE_DEBUG']
...
```

and my settings.ini looks like that :

```
[debug]
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
...
```

Any advice ?

Comment: If you want to use multiple databases, try this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Thanks. I've already seen this page. I think database routers might be sufficient but I rather prefer to find out about the wider opportunities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do sounds a little... off. I agree with Daniel Roseman. If you're looking for advise, listen to him. But if you're bent on trying to make this work, here's an idea: you MIGHT be able to do this from a view with a mixin that calls [settings.configure()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module):

```
from os
from django.conf import settings
import configparser

class DynamicSettingsViewMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'settings.ini'))

        settings.configure(**config['debug'])

        return super(DynamicSettingsViewMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class MyAwesomeAppView(DynamicSettingsViewMixin, TemplateView):
    pass
```

I haven't tried this... since it's crazy.

Comment: We know it's not something we should do... We have discussed with my team and I think we'll follow Daniel Roseman's advice. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apps don't, and can't, have separate settings. If you need to do this (which I must say sounds like a bad idea), you will need separate projects, each with their own settings.py, and each served by their own virtual server in Apache.

Comment: We know it's not something we should do... We have discussed with my team and I think we'll follow your advice. Thanks.